# Kotlin, jetpack compose: move braintree to separate class from mainactivity: AppCompatActivity(), dropinListener

Tags: android, inheritance, android-jetpack-compose, braintree

I want to move the braintree code from mainactivity to another class, but the DropInListener and AppCompatActivity() cause errors when I move them out of the mainactivity.

Part of the move is easy.
I can certainly create a class as such, but the problem is this class needs to inherit AppCompatActivity. When I do that, it creates a bigger project that i am not sure is the best way to do this. Ideally i would just like to instantiate the braintree class in the MainActivity, doesn't work either..

============================ Proposed class that does not work because of no AppCompatActivity=================

```
class Braintree constructor() : DropInListener {
  **private lateinit var dropInClient: DropInClient
  private lateinit var braintreeClient: BraintreeClient
  private lateinit var dataCollector: DataCollector**

    dropInClient = DropInClient(this@MainActivity, ExampleClientTokenProvider(commonRepository))
    dropInClient.setListener(this@MainActivity)
    braintreeClient = BraintreeClient(this@MainActivity, CLIENT_TOKEN)
    dataCollector = DataCollector(braintreeClient)
  }
  fun loadDropIn() {
    val dropInRequest = DropInRequest()
    dropInClient.launchDropIn(dropInRequest)
  }
  // Function to check and request permission.
  private fun checkPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
  }
  private fun collectDeviceData(paymentMethodNonce: String?) {
    dataCollector.collectDeviceData(MainActivity.INSTANCE) { deviceData, error ->
      val deviceDataObj = Gson().fromJson(deviceData, DeviceData::class.java)
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        if (paymentMethodNonce != null) {
          commonRepository.checkout(commonRepository.amount,
            commonRepository.uuid, paymentMethodNonce, deviceDataObj.correlation_id)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  override fun onDropInSuccess(dropInResult: DropInResult) {
    Log.d("TAG2", "dropin success")
    val paymentMethodNonce = dropInResult.paymentMethodNonce?.string
    collectDeviceData(paymentMethodNonce)
  }
  override fun onDropInFailure(error: Exception) {
    if (error is UserCanceledException) {
      Log.d("TAG2", "dropin user cancelled : ${error.message}")
    } else {
      Log.d("TAG2", "dropin failure : ${error.message}")
    }
  }
}
```

============= Original code and want to move the items in bold out of the MainActivity class to a separate location/file/class/something=======================

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp @Inject constructor() : Application() {

  init {
    INSTANCE = this
  }

  companion object {
    lateinit var INSTANCE: MyApp
      private set

    val applicationContext: Context
      get() {
        return INSTANCE.applicationContext
      }
  }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DropInListener {
  @Inject lateinit var commonRepository: CommonRepository
  **private lateinit var dropInClient: DropInClient**
  **private lateinit var braintreeClient: BraintreeClient**
  **private lateinit var dataCollector: DataCollector**

  init {
    INSTANCE = this
  }

  companion object {
    lateinit var INSTANCE: MainActivity
      private set
  }


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
      val navController = rememberNavController()

      SnoozeForGoodTheme(false) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
          checkPermission(SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, 1)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
          checkPermission(USE_EXACT_ALARM, 1)
        }
        checkPermission(RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, 1)
        checkPermission(INTERNET, 1)

        NavHost(
            navController = navController, startDestination = SplashDirections.root.destination) {
              composable(route = SplashDirections.root.destination) {
                Log.d("TAG2", "going splash page")
                SplashContentFactory().Content(navController)
              }
             
         }
      }
    }

    **dropInClient = DropInClient(this@MainActivity, ExampleClientTokenProvider(commonRepository))
    dropInClient.setListener(this@MainActivity)
    braintreeClient = BraintreeClient(this@MainActivity, CLIENT_TOKEN)
    dataCollector = DataCollector(braintreeClient)
  }
  fun loadDropIn() {
    val dropInRequest = DropInRequest()
    dropInClient.launchDropIn(dropInRequest)
  }
  // Function to check and request permission.
  private fun checkPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
  }
  private fun collectDeviceData(paymentMethodNonce: String?) {
    dataCollector.collectDeviceData(MainActivity.INSTANCE) { deviceData, error ->
      val deviceDataObj = Gson().fromJson(deviceData, DeviceData::class.java)
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        if (paymentMethodNonce != null) {
          commonRepository.checkout(commonRepository.amount,
            commonRepository.uuid, paymentMethodNonce, deviceDataObj.correlation_id)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  override fun onDropInSuccess(dropInResult: DropInResult) {
    Log.d("TAG2", "dropin success")
    val paymentMethodNonce = dropInResult.paymentMethodNonce?.string
    collectDeviceData(paymentMethodNonce)
  }
  override fun onDropInFailure(error: Exception) {
    if (error is UserCanceledException) {
      Log.d("TAG2", "dropin user cancelled : ${error.message}")
    } else {
      Log.d("TAG2", "dropin failure : ${error.message}")
    }
  }**

}
```